# Chrome <span> background-color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with Chrome. I created a website, the html-code looks like that:

```
<div id="Content"> 
<h1><span id="back-color">Heading</span></h1> 
<p><span id="back-color">bla bla bla:</span></p> 
  <ul id="bild-liste"> 
    <li><span id="back-color"><a href="?section=Bilder&ID=1">AAAAAA</span></li> 
    <li><span id="back-color"><a href="?section=Bilder&ID=2">BBBBBB</span></li> 
    <li><span id="back-color"><a href="?section=Bilder&ID=3">CCCCCC</span></li> 
    <li><span id="back-color"><a href="?section=Bilder&ID=4">DDDDDD</span></li> 
    <li><span id="back-color"><a href="?section=Bilder&ID=5">EEEEEE</span></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

The interesting part of my css-stylesheet looks like the following:

```
#back-color
{
      background-color: white;
}
```

So I just want the color behind letters to be white. This works quite good in Opera, but when watching the site in Chrome, the background is only white behind the headline and behind "AAAAAA", but not behind the other elements of the list. That's quite confusing, because it only doesn't work in Chrome. Maybe someone has a solution for this problem. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An id may only be used once on a website. Use css classes instead

(Replace id="back-color" with class="back-color" and use .back-color instead of #back-color in your css-stylesheet

Comment: Hi MTilsted is right. @user1045983 you may find this article of interest http://css-tricks.com/818-the-difference-between-id-and-class/ on the differences between id's and classes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it also doesn't work with classes. There's still only the background behind the same words white.

Comment: Really? Do you have a website where the html is online?

Comment: The problem is you don't end your <a> tag. If you add the missing </a> tag it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! That's a stupid mistake! But I learned the difference between class and id, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`id` is used to reference a *unique* element, so using it multiple times will produce unexpected results.

`class`, on the other hand, is used to group elements together. For example:

```
<div class="indent">
```

You can have multiple elements that share a `class`. The CSS selector to reference a class is this:

```
.indent {
  foo: 'bar';
}
```

Try using a `class` instead of an `id` and see how things work.

Comment: thanks, I did it this way, but it doesn't work, too. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you post your website URL?